# OnChild event Listener is being called multiple times

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am currently using Value Event Listener in my Code to show messages and it does not shows any error but my only problem is when whenever i add a new send or receive a new message my whole list gets updated all the previous messages are called and it uses a lot of memory currently i am taking care of it my clearing recyclerview every time the value event listener is called but now i want to add Child Event Listener in place of value event listener to save memory but whenever i add child event listener my messages are shown multiple times in recyclerview but after i restart the activity there is only one message in recyclerview.

[image]

[image]

MyCode

> MessageActivity.java

```
    public class MessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CircleImageView profile_image;
    TextView user_name;

    FirebaseFirestore fstore;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    FirebaseUser fuser;
    DatabaseReference reference;

    Toolbar toolbar;
    ImageButton imageButton;
    EditText textsend;
    String userID;

    MessageAdapter messageAdapter;
    List<Chat> mChat;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    String TAG = "MyTag";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);

        fAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        fstore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        userID = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();


        profile_image=findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        user_name=findViewById(R.id.username);
        imageButton=findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
        textsend=findViewById(R.id.text_send);

        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recycler_view2);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        toolbar=findViewById(R.id.myToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        Intent intent=getIntent();
        fuser=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        String userid=intent.getStringExtra("userid");
        String username= intent.getStringExtra("UserName");
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userid);

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                user_name.setText(user.getFirst());

                if (user.getImageURL().equals("default")){
                    profile_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                } else {
                    //and this
                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(user.getImageURL()).into(profile_image);
                }

                readMessages(fuser.getUid(), userid, user.getImageURL());

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String msg=textsend.getText().toString();
                textsend.setText("");
                if (!msg.equals("")){
                    sendMessage(fuser.getUid(),userid,msg);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(MessageActivity.this,"Empty messages cant be send",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void sendMessage(String sender, final String receiver, String message) {

        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("sender", sender);
        hashMap.put("receiver", receiver);
        hashMap.put("message", message);


        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");

        String key = reference.push().getKey();
        reference.child(key).setValue(hashMap);



    }

    private void readMessages(String myid,String userid,String imageurl){
        mChat=new ArrayList<>();
        reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");




        reference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                Chat chat= dataSnapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
                assert chat!=null;
                if (chat.getReceiver().equals(myid) && chat.getSender().equals(userid)||
                        chat.getReceiver().equals(userid)&&chat.getSender().equals(myid)){
                    chat.setMessageId(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                    mChat.add(chat);
                    Log.d(TAG,"msg "+chat.getMessage());
                }
                messageAdapter=new MessageAdapter(MessageActivity.this,mChat, imageurl);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
                messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



            }


            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {




            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Chat chat=dataSnapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
                chat.setMessageId(dataSnapshot.getKey());

                mChat.remove(chat);
                messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }

        });





        /*
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mChat.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Chat chat=snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
                    assert chat != null;
                    if (chat.getReceiver().equals(myid) && chat.getSender().equals(userid)||
                            chat.getReceiver().equals(userid)&&chat.getSender().equals(myid)){
                            mChat.add(chat);
                            Log.d(TAG,"msg "+chat.getMessage());
                    }
                    messageAdapter=new MessageAdapter(MessageActivity.this,mChat, imageurl);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
                    messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

         */

    }

}
```

> MessageAdapter.java

```
    public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public static  final int MSG_TYPE_LEFT = 0;
    public static  final int MSG_TYPE_RIGHT = 1;

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Chat> mChat;
    String imageurl;

    FirebaseUser fuser;

    public MessageAdapter(Context mContext, List<Chat> mChat,String imageurl) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mChat = mChat;
        this.imageurl=imageurl;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MessageAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == MSG_TYPE_RIGHT) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.chat_item_right, parent, false);

            return new MessageAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
        }
        else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.chat_item_left, parent, false);

            return new MessageAdapter.ViewHolder(view);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Chat chat=mChat.get(position);
        holder.show_message.setText(chat.getMessage());

        if (imageurl.equals("default")){
            holder.profile_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        } else {
            Glide.with(mContext).load(imageurl).into(holder.profile_image);
        }

        holder.show_message.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                String message_id=chat.getMessageId();
                Task<Void> task = Utils.removeUser(message_id);
                task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext,"Message Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


                return true;
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mChat.size();
        }
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

         public TextView show_message;
         public ImageView profile_image;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        show_message=itemView.findViewById(R.id.show_message);
        profile_image=itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        fuser= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (mChat.get(position).getSender().equals(fuser.getUid())){
            return MSG_TYPE_RIGHT;
        }
        else {
            return MSG_TYPE_LEFT;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why ChildEventListener is commented out?

Comment: @AdarshYashvanth Its because when i use child event listener no messages are shown in MessageActivity so i am using value event listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code. Remove ValueEventListener calls. You should add your logic inside `onChildAdded`

```
reference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                    Chat chat= dataSnapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
                    assert chat!=null;
                    if (chat.getReceiver().equals(myid) && chat.getSender().equals(userid)||
                            chat.getReceiver().equals(userid)&&chat.getSender().equals(myid)){
                        mChat.add(chat);
                        Log.d(TAG,"msg "+chat.getMessage());
                    }
                    messageAdapter=new MessageAdapter(MessageActivity.this,mChat, imageurl);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
                    messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }


                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {



                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }

            });
```

Comment: After using your solution every message is called twice for example hello is printed twice hi is printed twice but when i open message activity after closing it i only see them printed once

Comment: You should remove ChildEventListener from reference OnDestroy or onBAckPressed

Answer (score 0):

Declarete ChildEventListener goblally:

```
 private ChildEventListener childEventListener;
```

In onViewCreated, assing the childEventListener:

```
 @Override
     public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
 ...
 childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
             @Override
             public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
                 //Your stuff here
             }
             ....
         };
 ...
 }
```

In method onStart add the listener to the Firebase reference:

```
 @Override
     public void onStart() {
         super.onStart();
         reference.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
     }
```

And remove the Listener in the OnDestoyView:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    reference.removeEventListener(childEventListener);
}
```